# Error using MIME::lite

Tags: perl, mime

I dont know if this error is specific to MIME::lite but I am getting it while I am trying to use smtp email with MIME.

```
No SASL mechanism found
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Authen/SASL.pm line 77
 at C:/Perl/lib/Net/SMTP.pm line 143
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Was the cause for this error ever determined? The marked answer really doesn't explicitly say how to fix it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess the smtp server you're trying to contact is configured to use authentication of some sort and MIME::Lite is trying to use SASL (http://asg.web.cmu.edu/sasl/) under the hood. At least *something is triggering SASL*  and you don't seem to have the right perl modules for it. The documentation for [Authen::SASL](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Authen-SASL-2.15/lib/Authen/SASL.pod) mentions [Authen::SASL::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Authen-SASL-XS-1.00/XS.pod) and [Authen::SASL::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Authen-SASL-2.15/lib/Authen/SASL/Perl.pod) depending on your setup, the latter being pure perl and probably easier to run on windows. Below these two are the actual mechanism implementations e.g. Authen::SASL::Perl::CRAM_MD5 which also need to be in place.

It would be easier to debug if you included some initialization code for the libraries.

Comment: What do you mean include initialization code for the libraries?

Comment: these?
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP;
use MIME::Lite;

Comment: No, the code you use to set up the objects you create supported by these modules.